# Problems with IP Oracle Cloud Instance VM

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'am trying different cloud options, I've tried digital ocean droplets and OVH instances, but when i create an ubuntu instance in oracle cloud my ip once i logged throug ssh, i have this:

```
IPv4 address for ens3: 10.0.0.3
```

I can't understad why, in other clouds the IP is the same as the public ip.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

10.0.0.3 is the Private IP address of the host. Every VM will have a Private IP regardless of whether it is in public or private subnet. This is the same IP used for accessing resources inside the same VCN thereby avoiding unnecessary routing of traffic over public internet. This should be very similar to other clouds.

A public IP object is associated with a Private IP whenever a VM is created in a public subnet. The public IP remains the same throughout the lifecycle of Private IP. Good part in Oracle cloud is, this is almost permanent until the VM is destroyed.

Regardless you will be able to access the VM using Public IP.

Answer (score 2):

To make it more easily understandable (if you have networking background), in OCI public IP addresses are associated with private IP addresses using one-to-one Network Address Translation, or more specifically DNAT.

The OCI's routing infrastructure forwards traffic destined to public IP address, to the corresponding private IP that you see on the instances VNIC and vice versa. This relationship is done by the service and you won't see the public IP assigned to the VNIC at all. You can also unassign the public IP and assign another one without affecting local private networking inside VCN. Or unassigning the public IP completely if necessary.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are trying to connect through a private IP which is not possible unless you are on the Orcale Cloud network. To make the connection you have to go to the Instance access section and there get the user and ip to connect through ssh.

[image]